# JavaFX - How to add Item to ListView from different Stage?

Tags: java, listview, javafx

How can i add an item to an already existing ListView from a different Stage (Window).

Basically i just want to add Text to the ListView from  Window 2 to the ListView in Window 1.

Thanks in advance.

Sorry i forgot this is what i've got so far in my controller class: (im a beginner in javafx ..)

(below i try to add a String to the ListView but this doesnt work...and i dont know why )

```
public class ClientGUIController implements Initializable {


    @FXML private Text usernameText;
    @FXML private Button cancelButtonNewDate;
    @FXML private TextField newDateTitel,newDateJahr;
    @FXML private TextArea newDateNotiz;
    @FXML private ComboBox<String> newDateTag,newDateMonat,newDateStunde,newDateMinute;
    @FXML private ListView<String> terminListView;


    private  ObservableList<String> termine = 
            FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     private ObservableList<String> listItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Add Items here");



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


    }

    public Text getUsernameText() {
        return usernameText;
    }

    public void setUsernameText(String username ) {
        this.usernameText.setText(username);

        terminListView.setItems(listItems);
        listItems.add("test");

    }



    public void newDate() {

        Stage newDate = new Stage();

        Parent root;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("newDate.fxml"));
//          FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
//          root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResource("NewDate.fxml").openStream());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        Scene sceneNewDate = new Scene(root);
//      sceneNewDate.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Style.css").toExternalForm());



        newDate.setTitle("Neuer Termin");
        newDate.setScene(sceneNewDate);
        newDate.show();


    }


    public void createNewDate() throws IOException {


//      Termine meinTermin = new Termine(Integer.parseInt(newDateTag.getValue()), Integer.parseInt(newDateMonat.getValue()), Integer.parseInt(newDateJahr.getText()), newDateTitel.getText(), newDateNotiz.getText(),
//              Integer.parseInt(newDateStunde.getValue()), Integer.parseInt(newDateMinute.getValue()));

        //Add item to ListView
        listItems.add("test"); <- this doesnt work



    }



    public void closeDialogue(){

          Stage stage = (Stage) cancelButtonNewDate.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far...

Comment: You set `listItems` as the items for `terminListView` in the `setUsernameText(...)` method. Where are you calling that method?

Comment: The method is called by the mainclass before showing the gui. usually i would set listitems as the item for terminListView in the initialize method. but if i do so the second window also calls initialize and throws a NullPointerException .

Comment: Can you show that code? And which is the second stage you mention? I can't really see how your code relates to your question.

Comment: ok , let me try to explain. the controller above controls the main gui with the ListView in it and opens a new window wenn newDate() is called. this new window has a button. I can't figure out how to add a new Item to my ListView (in the main gui) using that button from a seperate window (second stage create in newDate())

Comment: OK, but you say `listItems.add("test")` "doesn't work" (not sure what that means; throws an exception? just does nothing? blows your computer up?). So I assume you are calling that method from the controller for `newDate.fxml`. How are you passing the reference to the `ClientGUIController` to the second controller?

Comment: i doesnt do anything , no error just nothing. actually i only use this controller for both windows. i guess thats a no go  and i have to create a new controller class for the newDate.fxml? But then same question : how do i control the ListView from another controller :) Thanks so far really appreciate

Comment: Uh, yes. You should not use the same controller class for two different fxml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to pass `listItems` to the controller for `newDate.fxml`, so it can just add to that list. So, assuming the controller class for `newDate.fxml` is `NewDateController`, you would do something like:

```
public class NewDateController {

    private ObservableList<String> data ;

    public void setData(ObservableList<String> data) {
        this.data = data ;
    }

    // other code as before...

    // button handler:
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonPress() {
        data.addItem("test");
    }

}
```

Then in your `ClientGUIController`, load the fxml like this:

```
public void newDate() {

    Stage newDate = new Stage();

    Parent root;
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("newDate.fxml"));
        root = loader.load();
        NewDateController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setData(listItems);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    Scene sceneNewDate = new Scene(root);

    newDate.setTitle("Neuer Termin");
    newDate.setScene(sceneNewDate);
    newDate.show();


}
```

Comment: Thats it! I got it to work like that! Thank you very much James_D ! :)